# Azure DevOps 2020 - Find a file in a repo from multiple projects in a collection

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

we have Azure DevOps 2020.I have a collection with multiple project . Each project has multiple repos.Each repo has multiple branches

**Question** : I want to find all the repos in the projects which has a particular file ( example : `config.json` in the repo .

1. Is it possible to achieve this using TFS.exe or
2. can I achieve this using REST API's ? ***Direction should be helpful, I can write script in PowerShell or Python.***

or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no commandline that ships with Azure DevOps to do this query.

The simplest way is probably to use [Azure DevOps Search with the Code Search extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-code-search) if it's enabled on your instance. That allows you to search across all projects in the collection at once.

If that's not an option for you you'll need to use the REST API to query all projects in the collection, then [query all the repositories in the project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and [grab the tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/trees/get) and find the file you're after.

It may be simpler to clone the repository locally and use `git` to find the files you're after.

Comment: This seems reasonable, except I think the last sentence should probably say "clone *all the repositories* locally", which I agree is probably "simpler" but depending on how many there are and how big, it may not be "better". ;)

Comment: I believe the Code Search extension is limited only to the branches that have been configured to be indexed for search.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to code search in my environment.

so I'll assume tfs-git repository.

I would use powershell and the rest api to get a list of projects. Foreach project, get a list of tfs-git repos.  Foreach repo, clone it locally. Then, I'd try git search as suggested previously if a small number of repos. I'd fall back to windows search if that doesn't work.